# Javascript array reduce return zero instead of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

I've got an example array that I'm trying to reduce by the counts of the occurrence of a key (sentiment in this example):

```js
const sentimentLog = [
  {
    id: 1,
    createdOn: new Date('2020-02-13'),
    sentiment: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    createdOn: new Date('2020-02-12'),
    sentiment: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    createdOn: new Date('2020-02-12'),
    sentiment: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    createdOn: new Date('2020-02-11'),
    sentiment: 3
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    createdOn: new Date('2020-02-11'),
    sentiment: 2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    createdOn: new Date('2020-02-10'),
    sentiment: 1
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    createdOn: new Date('2020-02-10'),
    sentiment: 2
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    createdOn: new Date('2020-02-09'),
    sentiment: 1
  }
]
```

I'm using:

```js
const sentimentGrouped = (sentiments) => {
  return sentiments.reduce((hash, { sentiment }) => {
    hash[sentiment] = (hash[sentiment] || 0) + 1
    return hash
  }, [])
}
```

And it's nearly there. What I can't figure out is how to replace `undefined` when there's no sentiment scores of `0` (which is a possibility).

```js
console.log('sentimentGrouped', sentimentGrouped(sentimentLog))
```

The above produces:

```
"sentimentGrouped" [undefined, 4, 3, 1]
```

Whereas I'd like:

```
"sentimentGrouped" [0, 4, 3, 1]
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'll elaborate a bit further, there's 4 scores that will be returned (0 to 3). The data returned will be based on a date range. So there may be instances where there'll be no `1`s returned, similarly no `3`s returned by a different date range.

Comment: Is there a maximum sentiment value? Wondering if you can prefill the array with all zeros.

Comment: It's between 0 and 3 - so 4 options only - the UI represents these as smiley faces :)

Comment: beside pre populate the array with zeros (as you know the length of it in advance) is there a problem using an object as the hash?

Comment: I want to avoid an `object`, as I'm using the result within a `v-for` loop in Vue.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that if you never touch an element of the array, then it stays as a hole in the array, which means it's treated as undefined. Since you know the length of the array i would just prefill the array with zeros. Any sentiment score that does occur will be incremented. Any one that doesn't will stay with its initial value.

```
return sentiments.reduce((hash, { sentiment }) => {
  hash[sentiment] = hash[sentiment] + 1
  return hash
}, [0, 0, 0, 0])
```